# Ubuntu terminal: I can't seem to launch programs from my terminal anymore. I use sublime, rails and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, heroku, sublimetext3, zsh

I don't know when exactly this problem started or what caused it, but any command that implies calling a program or anything external to my terminal doesn't work. Here are a few examples:

```
stt
heroku open
rails s
```

These are the ones I use but it seems to be a pattern with opening something external. These commands appear green when I type them. stt is supposed to open sublime but doesn't anymore.
heroku open, doesn't open my app in the browser, and rails s connects to the local server but I have to open my app manually.
Any ideas ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer. Something was conflicting in my zshrc file (in the dotfiles), I probably had installed something, not sure what. I removed the following lines manually in the zsh file and everything is working again:

```
# Encoding stuff for the terminal
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export BUNDLER_EDITOR="subl $@ >/dev/null 2>&1 -a"
export BUNDLER_EDITOR="subl $@ >/dev/null 2>&1 -a"
export BUNDLER_EDITOR="subl $@ >/dev/null 2>&1 -a"
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.53:0
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.53:0
export BUNDLER_EDITOR="subl $@ >/dev/null 2>&1 -a"
```