# Rails, gems, require, zsh and an error message! I can't load my app because of an issue related to "require"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rubygems, zsh, require

So, I tried to repair something that was not working related to my ZSH file, which I managed to do, but ended up breaking some other stuff apparently :/
Anyway I am trying to run my app locally (actually all my apps run into the exact same problem) and it doesn't launch. I get a long list of script in the terminal which looks like this:

```
    122: from /home/olivier/code/OGsoundFX/rails-mister-cocktail/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    121: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    120: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    119: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    118: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    117: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    116: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    115: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    114: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    113: from /home/olivier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
```

I am not an expert, far from it, and I am a bit lost. It looks like this has something to do with "require". Everything was working this morning before I fixed the other issue, and broke this.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What did you fix?

Comment: Well, certain commands didn't work in my terminal anymore like: stt, heroku open or rails s. Actually I opened a ticket about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62025830/ubuntu-terminal-i-cant-seem-to-launch-programs-from-my-terminal-anymore-i-use       I tried re-installing oh-my-zsh before finally solving the problem, but bumping into this one instead

Comment: sounds like you wiped out your path environment setting.

Comment: Ouch! Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: This falls into the "it depends" category. Adding something like this to your `.zshrc`, `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` should get ruby and rails happy again (assuming you are in a rails project).  But I'd search for `running heroku locally` and `adding stt to terminal``

Comment: OK thanks  I'll look into that and let you know!

Comment: OK I solved it, I just needed to bundle update for some reason. I had tried bundle install several times, but didn't think of updating the gems. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it, I just needed to 'bundle update' for some reason. I had tried 'bundle install' several times, because the problem did seem related to gems, but I didn't think of updating the gems.